# Stored procedure for a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I got a select statement. I want to add a join to this select statement and the join which I want to add is at the bottom of this code. why am I unable to add one more left outer join for this select statement? The join which I want to add is at the bottom. I also need to write a stored procedure for the entire select statement:

```
SELECT
    FactId, UserType,
    wr.WorkRequestId, wr.XerisUserKey, 
    xu.CsuserUserID UserId, 
    u.fname UserFName, u.lname UserLName,
    b.PatientId, p.firstname PatFName, p.lastname PatLName,
    GroupId, HospiceGroupKey GroupKey, WR.ContactKey,
    C.ContactId, C.FirstName, C.LastName,
    Convert(datetime, (Convert(varchar, SD.Date, 101) + ' ' + ST.TimeOfDay ))  Start_dtm,
    Convert(datetime, (Convert(varchar, CD.Date, 101) + ' ' + CT.TimeOfDay ))  End_dtm,
    DATEDIFF(s,Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, SD.Date, 101) + ' ' + ST.TimeOfDay)),
    Convert(datetime, (Convert(varchar, CD.Date, 101) + ' ' + CT.TimeOfDay )))  WRDuration,
    (Convert(Decimal(18, 3), DATEDIFF(s, Convert(datetime,(Convert(varchar, SD.Date, 101) + ' ' + ST.TimeOfDay )),
    Convert(datetime, (Convert(varchar, CD.Date, 101) + ' ' + CT.TimeOfDay ))))) * 
                (Convert(Decimal(18,3),LineItemCount)/Convert(Decimal(18,3),PatientBucketItemCount)) Duration,
    CallBackNumber, WorkRequestType,
    B.LineItemCount, ArchiveLocation, Processed,
    ArchiveQueueType, TQA, Exclude, CallId
FROM 
    bi.dbo.FactWorkRequestTouches (NOlock) WR
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.BridgePatientWorkRequest B ON B.WorkRequestId = WR.WorkRequestId
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.dimPatient (NOlock) P ON B.PatientId = P.CphPatientID
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimXerisUsers (NOlock) XU ON WR.XerisUserKey = XU.XerisUserKey
INNER JOIN 
    cdc.dbo.csuser (NOlock) U ON XU.CsuserUserID = u.user_id
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimTimeOfDay (NOlock) ST ON WR.StartTimeOfDayKey = ST.TimeKey
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimTimeOfDay (NOlock) CT ON WR.CompletedTimeOfDayKey = CT.TimeKey
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimDate (NOlock) SD ON WR.StartDateKey = SD.DateKey
INNER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimDate (NOlock) CD ON WR.CompletedDateKey = CD.DateKey
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    bi.dbo.DimContact (Nolock) C ON WR.ContactKey = C.ContactKey
WHERE 
    CompletedDateKey = '20140131'
    AND ArchiveQueueType = 0
    AND PatientBucketItemCount <> 0
    AND Exclude = 0
    AND P.ENDDate is Null
```

This is the join I want to add to this select statement

```
left outer join 
    ssdba.excelleRx_WebFOCUS.dbo.DimHospiceHiearchy (nolock) h on b.groupid = h.group_id
```

Comment: Edit your post to show us what the query looks like when you add the `JOIN` and tell us what error you get.

Comment: Add your JOIN before the WHERE,if I intuit correctly.

Comment: I am getting an error         Msg 4122, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

Comment: Msg 4122, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Remote table-valued function calls are not allowed.

Comment: @RBarryYoung  The join which I added is at the bottom and I added it before where statement

Comment: @Mihai I added it but I am getting this error

Comment: Take out the `(NoLock)` from the JOIN you are adding.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to call a table valued function remotely (ie across servers).

There is a workaround here:
[Workaround for calling table-valued function remotely in SQL Server has even more issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982360/workaround-for-calling-table-valued-function-remotely-in-sql-server-has-even-mor)

And more info here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1f0d2885-faa2-496a-b010-edc441260138/remote-tablevalued-function-calls-are-not-allowed?forum=transactsql

Comment: Actually there is error with nolock. Got solution. Thanks for spending time to help