# How to get the result sets from tsql's execute?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, execute, linked-server

I try to remotely query table-valued function as it is offered in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10982500/921054).

But I stumbled over how to get the returned result sets to further work with them in sql code...

Calling UDF remotely is not supported by SQL Server and `openquery` cannot have parameters - only static string.

```
declare @query nvarchar(max) = 'select * into #workingDays from openquery(LNKDSRV, ''select * from DB.dbo.fxn_getWorkingDays('''''
    + cast(@date1 as nvarchar(max))
    + ''''',''''' 
    + cast(@date2 as nvarchar(max))
    + ''''')'')';
exec sys.sp_executesql @query;
```

When #workinDays is later queried there is a error *'invalid object name'*.

Comment: Any comment by the voter to close? What is wrong with this question?!

Comment: define "get". return results to a client? store in a temp table?

Comment: @Jeremy 'to further work with them in sql code...' temp table is a variant. will try exec + openquery

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7126382/stored-procedure-and-populating-a-temp-table-from-a-linked-stored-procedure-with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your table before sp_executesql to be available in the session:

```
Create table #tbl  
declare @query nvarchar(max) = 'insert into #tbl select * from....
exec sys.sp_executesql @query
select * from #tbl
```

Another option is to use global temp table `##tbl`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was mistakenly thinking that 'select * into #tempTable' when run with sp_executesql will create temp table in my scope.